# Browse a Node (Bitcoin Core) from xpub of any wallet to get the balance

Tags: bitcoin-core

I use my umbrel node with my wallet. For developing reasons i run a Bitcoin Core Node. Now i connect to my Bitcoin Core Node, but I can't figure how to scan an address. All the methods i found  https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list here are only if you have a Bitcoin Core Wallet. But i have an xpub from my wallet, where i create all the addresses from. I now need to browse those addresses in blockchain. How can I achive this?